# How to allow all applications to access keychain item without prompt from Terminal

Tags: ios, macos, codesign

I wrote a page in python Django and implemented the upload certificate to automate the function of signing ipa.

I'm use /usr/bin/codesign to sign an application, but macOS 10.14 show confirm prompt，how to use Terminal without prompt , I want to automated sign in application with web application!

[image]

Can't use this method： Keychain Access to allow all applications to access keychain，Because I want to automate python Django

[image]

Comment: Did you fix it? I need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with command line

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "keychainpassword" "keychainpath"
```